# Insert data into database table with text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data into a table and the code snipplet I saw seems to work for that person but for me!
I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I don't know database handling for asp.net. Can someone please tell me whats wrong with the code?

```
public partial class CompanyLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @".\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

    string sql = "insert into company values(@CompName, @BusinessType, @Pword)";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);
    string CompName = txtCompName.Text;
    string BusinessType = DropDownList1.Text;
    string Pword = txtPassword.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into company(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) Values(@CompName,@BusinessType,@Pword);";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName",SqlDbType.VarChar);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType",SqlDbType.VarChar);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pword",SqlDbType.VarChar);    

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

    txtCompName.Text = "";
    txtPassword.Text = "";
    DropDownList1.Text = "";
}
}
```

I fixed the code thanks to you guys but when I run it or when I click the register button I get the following error

ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Comment: your insert command should be refactored try using SQL Params instead..

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust  your query - `by deleting values`

```
 cmd.CommandText = "insert into company(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')
```

Nota : I suggest you also use `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue method`

And add this code :

```
    cmd.CommandText =  "insert into company(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) Values(@CompName,@BusinessType,@Pword);"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName",);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType",);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pword",);    

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: much cleaner response Candie than the rest +1 to you

Comment: I suggested he refactor his query to use Params and it's funny how others followed the same flawed approach with there responses I can't stand hard coded queries especially with all the damn quotes and double quotes..LOL

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

To:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
```

And:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')
```

To:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')";
```

**Additional:**

You should use parameterised queries. Never pass user input directly into a SQL statement as you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

```
string commandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values(@CompName, @BusinessType, @Pword)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@CompName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@BusinessType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
command.Parameters.Add("@PWord", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.CommandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "'");

try this....

Answer (score 0):

Check the line that begins with `cmd.CommandText` for errors in your quotes.

You might try instead using the `String.Format` method like this:

```
 cmd.CommandText = String.Format("insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('{0}','{1}','{2}')",CompName,BusinessType,Pword);
```

I've found that helps me keep track of concatenating variables much easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. In future code use parameters in sql commands!! See [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
2. Escape your connection string with @ in front of whole string or '\' before symbols that need to be escaped. [Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/57204ec7-b075-4d4c-8587-2eb53648441d).
3. `cmd.CommandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')` is missing `";` in the end.
4. `string sql = "insert into company values(@CompName, @BusinessType, @Pword)";
   OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);`
   and
   `cmd.CommandText = "insert into company values(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')`
   both are [setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sebfsz50.aspx) CommandText, so you can remove `sql` 
   and change
   `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);` to `OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();`

Answer (score 0):

1. connection was not opened
2. Unnecessary `sql` string with parametered query
3. syntax error in query (CommandText)

.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                       AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated 
                       Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    string CompName = txtCompName.Text;
    string BusinessType = DropDownList1.Text;
    string Pword = txtPassword.Text;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into company (CompName, BusinessType, Pword) 
                values('"+ CompName + "','"+ BusinessType + "','" + Pword + "')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

    txtCompName.Text = "";
    txtPassword.Text = "";
    DropDownList1.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below sample. Also wrap your connection & command inside `using clause`

```
  string yourConnectionString="";
    int result=0;
    using(OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(yourConnectionString))
    {

         string sql = "insert into company values(@CompName, @BusinessType, @Pword)";
         using (OdbcCommand cmd=new OdbcCommand(sql,conn))
         {   
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName",txtCompName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pword ",txtPassword.Text);  
            conn.Open();
            result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         conn.Close();
         if(result >0)
         {
           txtCompName.Text = "";
           txtPassword.Text = "";
           DropDownList1.SeletedIndex = -1;
         }    
    }
```